# Regex that match different format sentences in c#

Tags: c#, regex

Format of file

```
POS ID         PosScore NegScore    SynsetTerms                          Gloss
a   00001740    0.125   0           able#1"                              able to swim"; "she was able to program her computer";
a   00002098    0       0.75        unable#1                            "unable to get to town without a car"; 
a   00002312    0       0           dorsal#2 abaxial#1                  "the abaxial surface of a leaf is the underside or side facing away from the stem"
a   00002843    0       0           basiscopic#1                         facing or on the side toward the base
a   00002956    0       0.23        abducting#1 abducent#1               especially of muscles; drawing away from the midline of the body or from an adjacent part
a   00003131    0       0           adductive#1 adducting#1 adducent#1   especially of muscles;
```

In this file, I want to extract **(ID,PosScore,NegScore and SynsetTerms)** field. The **(ID,PosScore,NegScore)** field data extraction is easy and I use the following code for the data of these fields.

```
Regex expression = new Regex(@"(\t(\d+)|(\w+)\t)");

var results = expression.Matches(input);
foreach (Match match in results)
{

    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

and it give the correct result but the Filed **SynsetTerms** create a problem because some lines have two or more words so how organize word and get against it PosScore And NegScore.

**For example**, in fifth line there are two words `abducting#1` and `abducent#1` but both have same score.

So what will be regex for such line that get Word and its score, like:

```
  Word                PosScore          NegScore 
  abducting#1         0                 0.23
  abducent#1          0                 0.23
```

Comment: have you tried using a non-regex solution? This isn't too difficult to parse programatically from a plain string

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Regex split two variable words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118565/c-sharp-regex-split-two-variable-words)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The non-regex, string-splitting version might be easier:

```
var data =
   lines.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Skip(1)
        .Select(line => line.Split('\t'))
        .SelectMany(parts => parts[4].Split().Select(word => new
            {
                ID = parts[1],
                Word = word,
                PosScore = decimal.Parse(parts[2]),
                NegScore = decimal.Parse(parts[3])
            }));
```

Comment: A single space other than tab in the wrong place could really throw a wrench in things. I wonder if it would be better to enumerate every character in the string. The first, second, third, and fourth columns don't contain any whitespace, so reading and storing until the next whitespace is easy. Each item in the fifth column could be assumed part of a list until the reader hits whitespace followed by a double quote, marking the start of the sixth column and another double quote marking the end. The only problem is each item in the sixth column needs to be surrounded by quotes.

Comment: @Tim:  What you've posted is a valid answer.  You should flesh it out with some code and post as an answer.

Comment: @AustinSalonen: this is the format SentiWordNet file and i want to store in Database You can see in this  [Link](http://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it/download.php)

Comment: @ZiaRehman:  Storing in a database is beyond the scope of the question...  This will parse the tab-separated-values as defined in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex

```
^(?<pos>\w+)\s+(?<id>\d+)\s+(?<pscore>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+(?<nscore>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+(?<terms>(?:.*?#[^\s]*)+)\s+(?<gloss>.*)$
```

You can create a list like this

```
var lst=Regex.Matches(input,regex)
             .Cast<Match>()
             .Select(x=>
             new 
             {
                 pos=x.Groups["pos"].Value,
                 terms=Regex.Split(x.Groups["terms"].Value,@"\s+"),
                 gloss=x.Groups["gloss"].Value
             }
        );
```

and now you can iterate over it

```
foreach(var temp in lst)
{
    temp.pos;
    //you can now iterate over terms
    foreach(var t in temp.terms)
    {
    }
}
```